# gcloud ai-platform prediction from standard JSON file ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'framework'

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am trying to run an ML prediction request on a JSON file `records.json`.

`!gcloud ai-platform predict --model housing_prices --json-instances records.json`

I am getting the following error.

```
Using endpoint [https://ml.googleapis.com/]
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'framework'
```

All libraries are imported.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
```

I am following a qwiklabs [lab](https://googlecourses.qwiklabs.com/focuses/11582?parent=catalog) 'Predict Housing Prices with Tensorflow and AI Platform'. All commands are in Jupyter notebook on GCP using `tensorflow` framework. I am missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of the CLI: `gcloud --version`?

Comment: Thank you John, I did check the version. It's the latest 326.0. 0. - the Notebook is running on a Google managed latest CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to **resolve** the issue. :) Thanks @john-hanley for pointing me to check what I might have missed.

**Resolution:**

- ssh into the VM (although managed by GCP) I updated the gcloud components
- `$ gcloud components update`
- My prediction command `!gcloud ai-platform predict --model housing_prices --json-instances records.json`
- Threw the output as expected.

```
Using endpoint [https://ml.googleapis.com/]
PREDICTIONS
[24958.638671875]
[19435.654296875]
```

Comment: Just to close on this one. SDK gets released every week. DLVMs  (Notebooks OS) every 2 weeks. I would be interested in knowing which Notebook DLVM image and version you were using. As if the bug you pointed out was solved in a more recent release of SDK it would not be included in latest DLVM build based on what I stated above.

Comment: GCP AI Platform Notebooks - DLVM instance was TensorFlow Enterprise 1.15 (pre-installed with support for Keras), Without GPUs @gogasca, Thanks for following up.